# String replace doesn't appear to be working

Tags: python, string, replace

I initially tried using `=` operator to assign value but it returned an error,
then I tried using **`string.replace()`**:

```
encrypted_str.replace(encrypted_str[j], dec_str2[k], 2)
```

and

```
encrypted_str.replace(encrypted_str[j], unichr(ord(dec_str2[k]) - 32), 2)
```

But it is returning the orignal value.

Help out as to how to use the replace API properly to give the correct result
Also is there any other API that can be used instead of **`unichr()`**.

The `encrypted_str` is being taken from the user by `encrypted_str = raw_input()`
`dec_str2` is the freq string being input by user.
The issue hardly concerns the variable
I want to know if I am using the `replcae()` API incorrectly as it is giving me unchanged output for `encrypted_str`
Can we use `encrypted_str[j]` **would return a character from the string** to define the sub string for the `replace()` API.
I used `encrypted_str.replace(encrypted_str[j], unichr(ord(dec_str2[k]) - 32), 1)` **max replace 1
instead of 2** (as I need just the one replacement).

The actual operation that I need to be done will be in C as follows:
**`encrypted_str[j] = dec_str2[k] -32`**.

As I am new to python I am trying to find a substitute.

Comment: how you think we can help you without knowing about `encrypted_str` and `dec_str2` and actually whats the logic behind your code ?

Comment: I don't think it matters so much
But the logic is of deciphering Ceaser Cipher using decrypted freq string

Comment: please add your describe to question , and your data or a bit of them !

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Strings in Python are immutable. That means that a given string object will never have its value changed after it has been created. This is why an element assignment like `some_str[4] = "x"` will raise an exception.

For a similar reason, none of the methods provided by the `str` class can mutate the string. So, the `str.replace` method does not work the way I think you expect it to. Rather than modifying the string in place, it returns a new string with the requested replacements.

Try:

```
encrypted_str = encrypted_str.replace(encrypted_str[j], dec_str2[k], 2)
```

If you're going to be making many such replacements, it may make sense to turn your string into a list of characters, make the modifications one by one, then use `str.join` to turn the list back into a string again when you're done.

Comment: i forget about this every time is there some way to bookmark?

Answer (score 9):

Python strings are immutable. This means that a string cannot be modified by a method call as described in your post. You must use an assignment in order to use the returned string from your method call.

For example:

```
encrypted_str = encrypted_str.replace(encrypted_str[j], dec_str2[k], 2)
```

Now `encrypted_str` contains the new value.

Answer (score 0):

You should name it ,

```
str1 = "abc.."
print str1.replace("..","")
'abc'
print str1
'abc..'
str1 = str1.replace("..","")
print str1
'abc'
```

iterate :

```
    str = ['a','..']
    for i in str:
        str1= str1.replace(i, '')
    print(str1)
    #'bc'
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you have to strip the line first.

```
line = line.rstrip()
print(line.replace('', ''))
```

Comment: The question is not about this. And what do you want to say with the second line?

Comment: The second line does nothing, as it's replacing nothing with nothing.