# Python 3: How do I .join() input() With A String?

Tags: python

I want to join a users `input` to a `string`.

```
def Username():
    Name = ("Name:")
    Name.join(input("What's your Dicer's name?:\n"))
    print(Name)
Username()
```

If I were to `input` the name `'Bradley'` for `input()` here is the results:

```
What's your Dicer's name?:
 Bradley
Name:
```

It didn't `print` what I wanted even though I joined the `input` with `"Name:"`. Here is what I was expecting. Why is it not occurring?

```
What's your Dicer's name?:
 Bradley
Name: Bradley
```

Comment: doing `Name.join(...)` creates a new string that you do nothing with, if you want to change the `Name` variable to the result of `Name.join(...)` then do `Name = Name.join(input("..."))` but I imagine you will be surprised with the result.

Comment: This isn't really what `join` is for, try running `help(str.join)`, it joins a bunch of strings together with `Name` as the seperator, in this case it does each letter of `Bradley` seperated by `"Name:"` so the result will be: `'BName:rName:aName:dName:lName:eName:y'` instead I think you want `Name += input(...)` or just `name = input() ; print("Name:",name)`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943256/python-string-replace-not-working

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen That stack question was hard to understand. I also stuck with the `Name += input(...) ` one but thanks for your clarification

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't calling a string method do anything unless its output is assigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189172/why-doesnt-calling-a-string-method-do-anything-unless-its-output-is-assigned)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I will be quite honest with you. I haven't used that account or python in a long time.

Comment: Ah. I am just trying to get the question closed, because I am pretty confident it was a duplicate. I am allowed to close questions unilaterally if they were originally tagged `python`, but this question was originally tagged with `python-3.x` and *not* with `python`, so I have to wait for assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.join` is an overkill for this. You can simply concatenate the user input to `Name` using `+`:

```
def Username():
   Name = "Name: "
   Name += input("What's your Dicer's name?:\n")
   print(Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `join` method of string expects a list (iterable) to join using the string itself. For example:

```
>>> "-".join(["one", "two"])
'one-two'
```

joined the list `["one", "two"]` with the `"-"` string.

I expect you want something like:

```
" ".join(["Name:", input("Enter name:")])
```

joining the string `"Name:"` with the value returned by `input`.

But that's a bit hard to read. You might be better off with [format](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
name = input("Enter name: ")
print("Name: {}".format(name))
```

Comment: The second answer works but it strays away from the `Name` tuple concept

Answer (score 0):

Why don't your something like.

```
ans = input("What's your Dicer's name?:\n")
print("Name:"+ans)
```

It will give you what you want. 
It is the best way to solve the problem what you want. Join is not appropriate in this situation.

Cheers,
John

Comment: Although this also works it strays away from the `Name` tuple and I need that for later

Answer (score -1):

This isn't how str.join() works.  The method takes a list or sequence of strings, and joins them into one string, with the "parent" string demarcating the listed values.  In your case you most likely want to call

```
print( " ".join([Name, input( "What's your Dicer's name?:\n" ) ] ))
```

This will put a space between both strings in the list.

EDIT: As noted in comments above, this isn't a mutating method, and instead returns an entirely new string, which you will have to keep under a new or existing variable.

Reference: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm

Comment: This is giving me an invalid snytax.

Comment: It still isn't working and it gives me the same error