# How to replace a specific word in specific line starting with a "keyword" python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've tried to write python code to do the following, and I'm stuck. Please help.

I have this file "names.txt"

```
rainbow like to play football

however rainbow ... etc

names = rainbow, john, alex 

rainbow sdlsdmclscmlsmcldsc.
```

I need to replace rainbow word to (Removed) in line which starts with "name = "

I need the code to search for keyword " name = "
and replace the word "rainbow" to " (Removed") in the same line without changing the words rainbow in other lines, then overwrite the file "names.txt" with the changes to be like:

```
rainbow like to play football

however rainbow ... etc

names = (Removed), john, alex 

rainbow sdlsdmclscmlsmcldsc.
```

Thanks

Comment: show us the code, and are you checking for 'name =' or 'names ='

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. It will be easier for us to help you.  And please check your Grammar.

Answer (score 0):

This will work in both Python 2.7 (which you used as a tag) and Python 3.

```
import fileinput
import sys

for line in fileinput.input("names.txt", inplace=1):
    if "names = " in line:
        line = line.replace("rainbow", "(Removed)")
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

See "Optional in-place filtering" [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) (Python 2.7.13) or [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/fileinput.html) (Python 3.6).

Comment: The `if` condition is weak.

Comment: It is what the question requested. Without further clarification, it is the best that can be done.

Answer (score -1):

Avoiding regex, here is one way of doing it

```
with open("names.txt") as f:
  content = f.readlines()
```

This was stated in [How do I read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list-with-python) and was found using google searching "stack overflow best way of reading in a file python". Then take this content, and do the following.

```
new_list_full_of_lines = [] # This is what you are going to store your corrected list with
for linea in content: # This is looping through every line
  if "names =" in linea:
    linea.replace ("rainbow", "(Removed)") # This corrects the line if it needs to be corrected - i.e. if the line contanes "names =" at any point
  new_list_full_of_lines.append(linea) # This saves the line to the new list
with open('names.txt', 'w') as f: # This will write over the file
  for item in new_list_full_of_lines: # This will loop through each line
    f.write("%s\n" % item) # This will ensure that there is a line space between each line.
```

Reference - [String replace doesn't appear to be working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943256/python-string-replace-not-working)

Other reference - [Writing a list to a file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/writing-a-list-to-a-file-with-python)