# Replace function isn't working anymore on String in Python

Tags: python, string

```
s = "AMCDEFGHI"
s.replace('A','X')
print(s)
```

Output: "AMCDEFGHI"

Could anyone please let me know if developers have extracted this functionality.

Comment: Duplicate: [String replace doesn't appear to be working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943256/string-replace-doesnt-appear-to-be-working)

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable, you need to assign the value return by replace to new string

```
s = "AMCDEFGHI"
s = s.replace('A','X')
print(s)
```

Comment: Thank you..Later I found the same:)

Answer (score 0):

Strings in Python are immutable, so you will have to reassign `s` to the replace call in order for it to stick:

```
s = "AMCDEFGHI"
s = s.replace('A','X')
print(s)
```

This prints:

```
XMCDEFGHI
```

Answer (score 0):

use this instead

```
    s = "AMCDEFGHI"
    s=s.replace('A','X')
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to assign it to s

```
s = "AMCDEFGHI"
s=s.replace('A','X')
print(s)

result is XMCDEFGHI
```