# Changes not taken into account in dictionary values

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have specific letters `â€™` that I want to remove from the string values in a dictionary wherever they are found. However, I don't know why a single change on a specific key works, while when looping on the whole dictionary doesn't.

The loop used is:

```
data_nv = {
    '00254325': 'remove something and something else etc etc â€™, do this',
    '00348956': 'have fun here and here theâ€™n get this and that'
}

for key in data_nv:
    if 'â€™' in data_nv[key]:
        data_nv[key].replace('â€™', ' ')
```

If I do a replacement like the one below it works.

```
data_nv['00254325'].replace('â€™', ' ')
```

Comment: `replace()` returns a new string. It does not modify the original.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String replace doesn't appear to be working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943256/string-replace-doesnt-appear-to-be-working)

Comment: The proper solution would be to fix whatever produced that mojibake in the first place. It looks like you are importing UTF-8 into a Windows-1252 context without properly translating it, or possibly improperly translating content which is already UTF-8 on the assumption that its encoding is Windows-1252 (or some other legacy 8-bit encoding). If you have literally the bytes 0xE2 0x80 0x99 that's UTF-8 for a single quote [U+2019](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm).

Comment: Better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189172/why-doesnt-calling-a-python-string-method-do-anything-unless-you-assign-its-out

Comment: Yes triplee, I noticed I have this encoding/decoding problem with my data that I need to fix

Answer (score 2):

`str.replace` returns a value with the replacement happend. You need to store the value back into the dictionary:

```
data_nv={'00254325': 'remove something and something else etc etc â€™, do this', 
         '00348956': 'have fun here and here theâ€™n get this and that'}

for key in data_nv:
    if 'â€™' in data_nv[key]:
        # store replaced value back in dict under key
        data_nv[key] = data_nv[key].replace('â€™', ' ')

print(data_nv)
```

Output:

```
{'00254325': 'remove something and something else etc etc  , do this',
 '00348956': 'have fun here and here the n get this and that'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found it,

We can use the re library like this:

```
for key in data_nv:
    if 'â€™' in data_nv[key]:
        data_nv[key]=re.sub(r'â€™',' ',data_nv[key])
```