# creating multiple iteration of the same code

Tags: python

beginer question:
I often have to repeat the same line of code 10 times for 10 different variables (i read you can't or should not create variable dynamically)

I thought to help me once i written it once I could iterate with a find replace (I am currently doing it in word)

I wrote this but get tons of error when i input code like if console trying to execute  the code. what am i missing? is it because i paste it i the console does it need to be imported from a ext file ?

```
LineOfCode = input("Enter the code you want to iterate the iteration variable need be 8")
for i in range(10):
    LineOfCode.replace("8",str(i))
    print(LineOfCode)
```

Comment: `with a find replace (I am currently doing it in word)` - there are quite a few free Python editors/IDE's. You should try those out rather than using word.

Comment: You can use dicts when you need something like "creating variables dynamically".

Comment: `get tons of error` - When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`). Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: Yeah, Word most definitely isn't a good editor for programming. Even Notepad is better, in my opinion. You should use some simple and lightweight text editor, like Sublime Text, or a lightweight IDE, like Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Related: [String replace doesn't appear to be working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943256/string-replace-doesnt-appear-to-be-working),

Comment: Not enough details, but i tried my best to help you

Comment: @wwii "rather than using word" - the OP might have meant not the program MS Word, but the word of a phrase ? In this context, the sense of it might be "i did not replace it in the code, but rather in a string". The OP should definitely ad more details.

Comment: Does [Why doesn't calling a Python string method do anything unless you assign its output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189172/why-doesnt-calling-a-python-string-method-do-anything-unless-you-assign-its-out) answer your question?

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer i realise now my question was not clear enough (i do use VS Code but to copy the same code multiple times just used the find replace functionality of word)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost correct:

`String.replace()` returns a new string with the changes, doesn't change the existing string. So the code should be like:

```py
LineOfCode = input("Enter the code you want to iterate the iteration variable need be 8")

for i in range(10):
    var = LineOfCode.replace("8", str(i))
    print(var)
```

The question isn't clear enough, so if this isn't what you wanted, edit the question.

Besides this, you can use Visual Code as an IDE, it'll make things much, much easier than Word.

About the errors, I think you might be trying to run the code directly in console. Instead of typing only the file name, type `python file.py`, assuming the file name is file. The file must be a python file (ending with .py), also it shouldn't be saved as a word file. It must be plain text.

Comment: thanks a lot, I am using VS code but for the particular task of find replace I used Word

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the same code on multiple variables, you can create the code as a string, and then use the builtin `exec` to execute it. Example:

```py
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
variables = ["a", "b", "c"]
for var in variables:
    exec("print(" + var + ")") # print the variable before modifying
    exec(var + " *= 2") # multiply the current variable by 2
    exec("print(" + var + ")") # print the variable after modifying
```

If this is not what you need, your question was not clear enough and i misunderstood it, you just have to provide more information on what excatly you need by adding a comment under your question, in which you first type `@Programmer` and then your text.